# Doing UI Work in the background

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms, multithreading

What's the simplest way to do background work with the UI and also know when it has ended?

Comment: You may want to specify which you want:  Do you want to do ui work in the background (like build it and display complicated graphics) or do you want the GUI to kick off work done in the background but have the UI remain responsive?

Comment: @bill K - I would like to perform a Database query and populate a ListView control in the background.

Comment: Do you want to keep the UI alive while running the query or do you want to update the ListView control each time you get new data? If the partial update is not really needed, you should not do it. The first alternative is easier to implement and it should also have better performance.

Comment: @mgronber - I am happy with the first alternative.

Comment: @J.T.S.: Then check the link that I have posted in my answer. It should make it pretty clear how you can store the intermediate data.

Answer (score 2):

Try a backgroundworker

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: I have, thats what is giving me grief: "Cross-thread operation " error... I am trying to populate a listview control in the background using backgroundworker

Comment: JTS - You must used the ProgressChanged event on the BackgroundWorker to do the updates - you can't do them from the background work itself.

Comment: And if you need to interact with the UI from another thread have a look at invoke/begininvoke

Comment: I understand that, but how am I able to pass every single row/column info retrieved from the database from inside the DoWork method to the ProgressChanged event? I have thought of that, but cannot do it. I don't see how I can?

Comment: @Fredrik Leijon - If I return it as a DataSet, can I then do something like listView1.Data = dataSet1; ? (for example) So inside the ProgressChanged event, I can just transfer everything inside the dataset into the listview?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you would benefit from [Threading in C#, part 3](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx) by Joseph Albahari. Especially the section "*Subclassing BackgroundWorker*" should be useful.